# Jquery validation plugin question

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

i need to validate the account number, it can be either 6 number (111111), or two letter then 6 numbers (xx111111).

Can someone please show me how to do it? thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Teja says, you need to use `.addMethod` with a regular expression. I believe this should work:

```
$.validator.addMethod("accountnumber", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(\w{2})?\d{6}$/.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid account number");


$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        account: {
            accountnumber: true
        }
    }

});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/tUaB7/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [addMethod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) method on the validation plugin as shown in the example and modify the regex to match your criteria..